Non-breakable space before every inline math
What I don´t want: When I write a sentence like One is $1$., I don't want Latex to break the line before the inline math (that particular example is horrible cause the new line would start with 1., which is terrible for the reader). I also do not want to write One is~$1$ every time.
What I want: I want Latex to typeset One is $1$. as if I had written One is~$1$.
In general I want text text text $inline math$ to be typeset as text text text~$inline math$.

Welcome! I can understand your request for short formulas like $1$, but do you really want it for longer ones? Also, please add a small but complete example showing the problem.

it's possible but it would be almost sure to break something and as mikep says it's not clear you'd want this for longer formulae, ~ is no more characters to type than   so honestly I wouldn't do this

Yeah, sorry if I sound rough, but I'm tired of this culture of "Why do you want that?", "Not a good idea", "I wouldn't do that". Cause what I want is well-defined and I couldn´t express it more clearlly than my last sentence (In general, ). I'm perfectly fine with "No way to do that", if that's the case. But if it's not, then just give me the gun and let me shoot myself on the foot.
